# Converting to Date time

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

Is there an easy inbuilt method in ruby which converts "20130313T113000Z" to a ruby Date format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [DateTime::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse):

```
DateTime.parse("20130313T113000Z")
  => #<DateTime: 2013-03-13T11:30:00+00:00 ((2456365j,41400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Or use `Date.parse` if you don't need the hours, minutes and seconds.